# Struts 2 is not populating HashMap<String, String>

Tags: struts2

I'm trying to update a map using struts 2 form. Iterating over the map displays the key value pair correctly, but when I submit the form, map is not getting populated. 
Key is a string with characters like . and /. Here is an example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("utilities.student_info.note", "note");

<s:iterator value="map" var="property" status="status">
  <s:property value="%{key}"/>
  <s:textarea name="map[%{key}]" value="%{value}" rows="5" cols="60"/>
</s:iterator>
```

I tried using quotes like this: `name="map['%{key}']"`, but it still doesn't work. 
I can see from the logs that the `ParamsInterceptor` is setting the params correctly: `map[utilities.student_info.note] => [note]`. But the map is empty on the action side. 
If I use `name="map[%{#attr.status.index}]"`, it populates the map, but the key is an index `(map[0] => [note])` which is not right.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How/when do you create the map?

Comment: Map is created and populated in the action's prepare() method. I think the struts is unable to interpret the key as string if it contains special characters. It populates the map just fine, if I remove the special characters in the key (name=map['utilities']) and as I mentioned before, it also works if I use the loop index as the key. But I want the map with key stored as this: "utilities.student_info.note".

Comment: Why do you want to use a map instead of using objects? In any case, what version of S2?

Comment: These key and value pairs are read from an inputstream and stored into java.util.Properties object, but I need to use Map in the form in order to include some additional properties.

Comment: @sneha try this <s:property value="key"/>    <s:debug/> always use the objects available with in action context and why can't you use resource bundle as you told reading from properties file and putting in map.

Comment: do you have `getter` and `setter` for map?

Comment: I just copied your code into my project, everything is fine, please check it you got `getter`

Comment: You don't need a setter for the map, just a getter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which Struts2 version you are using but on 2.3.8 `map['utilities.student_info.note']` is not an accepted parameter. Try `map['utilities_student_info_note']` and it should work. The key should be formed with word characters only.